# Is TestNG needed to run parallel tests using Selenium Grid?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Do I really need to use TestNG to execute parallel tests using Selenium grid for Windows and Mac machines? I am using C# Visual Studio 2013. I am a newbie in both Selenium and Selenium grid. Thanks and hoping for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use MBUnit, follow below link:

[Click Here](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/03/webdriver-c-test-scripts-execution.html)

Comment: Thanks Sadik, how about the multi threading? I am not sure if this would work and make our lives easier than using these test frameworks?